# Prevent the console from clearing the screen?

Tags: linux, kernel, console

When booting into Linux, there are sometimes one or two lines that get quickly cleared. I think that some of them don't even appear in dmesg. If nothing else, I want to suppress the clear before the "login:" prompt. Is there a kernel command or sysctl that I can set to prevent this so I can read them on the console screen after booting?

Comment: Doesn't /var/log/kern.log help? Or you don't have it?

Comment: See `/var/log/boot.log` for the missed messages, in case you've not yet managed to prevent the console clearing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the information you want will be in `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/messages` after the system boots, you should check those files first.

Generally linux machines run [mingetty](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mingetty8.html) for the virtual terminals.  If you have a traditional sysv init system, those are controlled by `/etc/inittab`.  You can add the `--noclear` option to mingetty to prevent clearing the screen.  To do this, edit `/etc/inittab` and change this line:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty1
```

to

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --noclear tty1
```

then reboot the machine.

Some newer linux distros use init replacements like Upstart (for example, Ubuntu).  These generally don't use /etc/inittab and instead use some other config files.  Here's a [discussion of how calling mingetty works on Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/67415).

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that I indeed care about Ubuntu. The link above points to some out-of-date information, and my first attempt (just edit /etc/init/tty1.conf was not at all successful.

Comment: They use `getty` from `util-linux`, not `mingetty`, but this works with Debian as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

With systemd things are different.  See article [Stop Clearing My God Damned Console](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SystemdNoClear).  In short:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d
cat >/etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/noclear.conf <<EOF
[Service]
TTYVTDisallocate=no
EOF
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Verify the result with `systemctl cat getty@tty1.service`

Answer (score 4):

If nothing else helped, you can grab your laptop and capture all the kernel log through serial console by adding something like this to kernel parameters:

```
console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8 console=tty0
```

This will cause output to apperar on serial console (in your terminal program) and on standard tty. Sometimes SOL (Serial Over LAN) is available.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of googling, I found the solution in [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/how-to-inhibit-the-clear-screen-before-login-prompt-825386/) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92054/log-boot-messages-on-tty1-instead-of-tty7). This procedure works for `Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS` as also described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/195926/63606), but it should not differ too much for other distributions.

First, add **`console=tty1`** to your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` (I also suggest to add **`noplymouth`** to inhibit `plymouth` and its useless splashscreen).

```
#> sudo vi /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1 noplymouth"
```

This forces the kernel log to be printed on `tty1` instead of `tty7` and avoid the `tty` switch before the login prompt.

Then just go into `/etc/init` and edit one or more of `tty1.conf`, `tty2.conf`, `tty3.conf`, `tty4.conf`, `tty5.conf`, `tty6.conf` or `console.conf`. I edited them all adding **`--noclear`** option to the `getty` command. For example, editing `tty1.conf`:

```
#> sudo vi /etc/init/tty1.conf
```

you'll have to replace:

```
respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

with:

```
respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 --noclear tty1
```

That's all, now your system should boot in a single `tty` without clearing it.

Answer (score 1):

`dmesg` here goes back to the very beginning of the kernel, starting with

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

Perhaps this is some bios message or part of your boot loader?  Either way, there are so many different things that can blank the screen, without knowing where exactly in the process it happened it's hard to say what to do about it.  Is the only thing left on the screen "Login:"? or is there some other boot-up stuff above it?  If it's immediately before the login prompt and nothing else is on the screen, then perhaps `/etc/issue` has a screen-blanking command in it?  Otherwise, you could be using some kind of console frame buffer that is switching the video mode.  On my computer, the screen is blanked when a console font is loaded.

Comment: TL;DR `/etc/issue` can be a culprit, too.  Good hint.